# Python: Mapping from intervals to values

Tags: python, range, intervals

I'm refactoring a function that, given a series of endpoints that implicitly define intervals, checks if a number is included in the interval, and then return a corresponding (not related in any computable way).
The code that is now handling the work is:

```
if p <= 100:
    return 0
elif p > 100 and p <= 300:
    return 1
elif p > 300 and p <= 500:
    return 2
elif p > 500 and p <= 800:
    return 3
elif p > 800 and p <= 1000:
    return 4
elif p > 1000:
    return 5
```

Which is IMO quite horrible, and lacks in that both the intervals and the return values are hardcoded.
Any use of any data structure is of course possible.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
import bisect
bisect.bisect_left([100,300,500,800,1000], p)
```

here the docs: [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html)

Comment: Truly impressive. Super clean, and I believe very fast too.
It can also be easily extended in case one does need a non-natural ordering or something else in return, like a string:
import bisect
n = bisect.bisect_left([100,300,500,800,1000], p)
a=["absent","low","average","high", "very high", "extreme"]
a[n]

Comment: hmmm but this doesn't return "arbitrary values" it returns the index. How do I have it return the arbitrary value? I tried `p = 10
x = bisect.bisect_left(OrderedDict({10: 'a', 11: 'b'}), p)
print()
` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a take on this:

```
def check_mapping(p):
    mapping = [(100, 0), (300, 1), (500, 2)] # Add all your values and returns here

    for check, value in mapping:
        if p <= check:
            return value

print check_mapping(12)
print check_mapping(101)
print check_mapping(303)
```

produces:

```
0
1
2
```

As always in Python, there will be any better ways to do it.

Comment: Does not consider the case of p > 1000!

Comment: That is why I specified: "You could try a take on this"

Comment: That last sentence is ironic, considering the python philosophy of having preferably only one obvious way to do something.

Comment: BUG: It produces None if p is greater than the last endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed quite horrible. Without a requirement to have no hardcoding, it should have been written like this:

```
if p <= 100:
    return 0
elif p <= 300:
    return 1
elif p <= 500:
    return 2
elif p <= 800:
    return 3
elif p <= 1000:
    return 4
else:
    return 5
```

Here are examples of creating a lookup function, both linear and using binary search, with the no-hardcodings requirement fulfilled, and a couple of sanity checks on the two tables:

```
def make_linear_lookup(keys, values):
    assert sorted(keys) == keys
    assert len(values) == len(keys) + 1
    def f(query):
        return values[sum(1 for key in keys if query > key)]
    return f

import bisect
def make_bisect_lookup(keys, values):
    assert sorted(keys) == keys
    assert len(values) == len(keys) + 1
    def f(query):
        return values[bisect.bisect_left(keys, query)]
    return f
```

Comment: I like this one better than the one that has the most votes because of its more generalized/non-hardcoded form and because it is more in-depth.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:

```
d = {(None,100): 0, 
    (100,200): 1,
    ...
    (1000, None): 5}
value = 300 # example value
for k,v in d.items():
    if (k[0] is None or value > k[0]) and (k[1] is None or value <= k[1]):
        return v
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def which_interval(endpoints, number):
    for n, endpoint in enumerate(endpoints):
        if number <= endpoint:
            return n
        previous = endpoint
    return n + 1
```

Pass your endpoints as a list in `endpoints`, like this:

```
which_interval([100, 300, 500, 800, 1000], 5)
```

Edit:

The above is a linear search. Glenn Maynard's answer will have better performance, since it uses a bisection algorithm.

Comment: Lose the "previous" caper; it's quite redundant.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I guess the original code "inspired" me to use it. BTW, your use of the imperative might sound a bit gruff to some.

Comment: @Steef: You may wish to consider a humble suggestion that you might at your leisure revist your answer, note that **your answer still includes a redundant line of code**, and in the fullness of time, excise the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another way ...

```
def which(lst, p): 
    return len([1 for el in lst if p > el])

lst = [100, 300, 500, 800, 1000]
which(lst, 2)
which(lst, 101)
which(lst, 1001)
```