# compressing several elif statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I've written some code to find how close the diffs of two time series are to each other and do this by finding the distance from the expected difference locations from the nearest actual change and assigning a score based on how far off it is.

In that code I have something that looks like this:

```
nearest_change = np.abs(actual_changes[actual_changes == change].index - time).min()

minutes_off = nearest_change.seconds/60
if minutes_off < 15:
  sum += 1
elif minutes_off < 30:
  sum += .8
elif minutes_off < 45:
  sum += .6
elif minutes_off < 60:
  sum += .4
elif minutes_off < 65:
  sum += .2

return sum / count
```

Is there a more pythonic and concise way to achieve this sort of scoring?

Comment: Not a pythonic way, but
`sum += 1 - .2 * (minutes_off / 15) if minutes_off < 65 else 0` is pretty concise.

Comment: this seems like a primarily opinion based question since the best way to do it is fairly subjective.... but it is an interesting question.

Comment: related to [Python: Mapping from intervals to values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199053/python-mapping-from-intervals-to-values)

Comment: @PhuNgo It should be `sum += 1 - .2 * math.floor(minutes_off / 15) if minutes_off < 65 else 1` or `sum += 1 - .2 * (minutes_off // 15) if minutes_off < 65 else 1`.

Comment: @CodingLambdas [`*` first, `-` next, `if – else` last](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: @PhuNgo oh, sry. Forgot that.

Answer (score 1):

If your mappings are discrete and can't be described by a simple formula then you could create them with an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict([(15,1),(30,.8),(45,.6),(60,.4),(65,.2)])
for key,value in d.items():
    if minutes_off < key:
            s += value
            break
```

Note, I renamed `sum`, as `s` to avoid clash with Python built-in function.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, you would need a `break` in there. I am pretty sure you just forgot. It is `elif` in the code provided by Eric Blum, not `if`.

Comment: Your code doesn't follow the style guide though: There should be spaces after commas. And the part in the `if` block should be indented with 4 spaces in relation to the `for` block.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each threshold and increment by 0.2 each time.

```
thresholds = [15, 30, 45, 60, 65]
for time_diff in thresholds:
    if minutes_off < time_diff:
        sum += .2
    else:
        break
```

Depending on how many you need, dynamically creating the threshold list might be worth it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. I'd guess this one is better, although it uses more code to archieve the same effect and is slower. But it does avoid repetition.

```py
class ScoreAccessDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, f, **kwargs):
        self.f = f
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        iterator = iter(self.keys())

        try:
            best = next(iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            raise KeyError(item)

        for k in iterator:
            if self.f(best, item) < self.f(k, item):
                best = k

        return super().__getitem__(best)

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            return default
```

and to use it:

```
nearest_change = np.abs(actual_changes[actual_changes == change].index - time).min()

minutes_off = nearest_change.seconds / 60  # spaces between operands and the operator

d = ScoreAccessDict({15: 1, 30: 0.8, 45: 0.6, 60: 0.4, 65: 0.2, float('inf'): 0}, f = lambda x, y: x if x < y else -x)

return s + d[minutes_off]  # sum shouldn't be shadowed
```

But judging from your code, the values added should be calculated using a continuous function anyway. And that would be the most pythonic way.